# GAE and Local MysqlServer issue: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThreadGroup")

Tags: java, android, mysql, google-app-engine

I have already tried a solution and I have done several procedures to solve this problem, but without success. My last hope is this topic ...

I have a local Mysql server running and I'm using Google App Engine in Android Studio. My Backend can not communicate with my local database. I created a SQL database in Google and SQL when deployed on GAE, using google database works fine. The problem occur only on local environment.

My code:

```
public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {

        String url = null;

    try {
        if (SystemProperty.environment.value() == SystemProperty.Environment.Value.Production) {
            // Load the class that provides the new "jdbc:google:mysql://" prefix.
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver");
            url = "jdbc:google:mysql://XXXXXt:us-central1:YYYYYY/Project?user=root&password=xxxxx";
        } else {
            // Local MySQL instance to use during development.

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/Project?user=root&password=xxxxx";

            // Alternatively, connect to a Google Cloud SQL instance using:
            // jdbc:mysql://ip-address-of-google-cloud-sql-instance:3306/guestbook?user=root
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return DriverManager.getConnection(url);
}
```

**Gradle:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.34'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter();
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'appengine'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.49'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:1.9.34'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints-deps:1.9.34'
    compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-sqladmin:v1beta4-rev37-1.22.0'
    compile 'com.google.cloud.sql:mysql-socket-factory:1.0.2'
    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.40'
}

appengine {
    downloadSdk = true
    httpAddress = "0.0.0.0"
    appcfg {
        oauth2 = true
    }
    endpoints {
        getClientLibsOnBuild = true
        getDiscoveryDocsOnBuild = true
    }
}
```

**App-Engine:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <application>myApplicationId</application>
    <version>1</version>
    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>

    <system-properties>
        <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties" />
    </system-properties>
    <use-google-connector-j>true</use-google-connector-j>
</appengine-web-app>
```

Any suggestions?